# Can python figure out the most up to date directory?

Tags: python

I have six directories the follow the format

```
\home\mydir\myproject\2012-01-23_03-01-34
\home\mydir\myproject\2012-01-11_01-00-57
\home\mydir\myproject\2010-01-11_01-00-57
\home\mydir\myproject\2010-01-11_01-00-54
\home\mydir\myproject\2010-01-08_01-00-54
```

Note, the datetime as the final directory.  It is *exactly* this format and it is meant to indicate the time the directory it was created Now they all cotain the file name myfile.xml.  I want to parse out the latest and greatest myfile.xml.  Does python have any magic where it can tell the latest (i.e. most up to date directory) from the name format of the directory I am using? If it does not, does it have any magic where it can tell by the file timestamps who is the most up to date?  The OS is windows?

Another way of looking at this is that the most up to date directory will also have the highest number.

Thanks.

Comment: From this date format, you can just lexically sort the strings and the highest value is the latest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have those directory names in a list `dirs`, then `max(dirs)` will give you the latest.

Answer (score 1):

For getting OS information as to the age of the files see http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-stat.html - if you really need the "most up to date", and there's a chance the files in the directories could be modified, and so considered more up-to-date than files in directories with later names, going by what the OS says is more robust. If only the creation age given by the folder is relevant then [@Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) has you covered.